# How to select all custom element that inherit from a specific javascript class

Tags: javascript, web-component

right now I'm trying to have fun with the [webComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).
I have created a component that is supposed to represent a mother class to all my other translatable components. it works as I want at the moment, but I would like a way to select all the elements of the current document that inherits from this mother class.
something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('lsp-motherComposant');
```

doesn't works.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>WebComponentTest</title>
        <!-- motherComponent -->
        <link rel="import" href="components/lsp-translatable/lsp- 
        translatable.html" />
        <!-- child Component -->
        <link rel="import" href="components/lsp-button/lsp-button.html" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="lang">
            <option value="fr" selected>fr</option>
            <option value="en">en</option>
            <option value="zh">zh</option>
        </select>

        <lsp-button i18n="events" width="33%" gradient color1="0,0,0,0" 
        color2="128,0,128,1" direction="left"></lsp-button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
             window.onload = function(){
             document.getElementsByTagName('lsp-translatable');
             // => empty node list

             };
         </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

lsp-translatable.js:

```
class LspTranslatable extends HTMLElement {//some stuff}
customElements.define('lsp-translatable', LspTranslatable);
```

lsp-button.js:

```
class LspButton extends LspTranslatable {//some stuff}
customElements.define('lsp-button', LspButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't help you in production code but it's a development version of what you are looking for.

Chrome DevTools has a developer command [queryObjects](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#query-objects) that will return all instances of a class. In Chrome DevTools you could run the following:

```
queryObjects(LspTranslatable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)?

```js
const components = document.querySelectorAll('lsp-button');
console.log(components);
console.log(Array.from(components));
```

```css
lsp-button {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #6F6;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<lsp-button id="button-0"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-1"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-2"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-3"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-4"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-5"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-6"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-7"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-8"></lsp-button>
<lsp-button id="button-9"></lsp-button>
```

Comment: hi, thx for the help, queryselectorAll can grab a custom webComponent by this name, the problem is i don't have any motherComponent in my document only childs, for the moment i've added a attribute shared with others childs but maybe there is a better way

Comment: @r-sede Can you update your question to include the actual markup? I only used `lsp-motherComposant` as the element because that's what the code in your question was trying to grab.

Comment: Not a huge deal these days but document.querySelectorAll is undefined in IE 7, probably a good idea to use jQuery

Comment: i want every element that inherit from a motherComposent while the mother composant is not actually on the page.document.getElementsByTagName('mother-composant') doesn't work if you don't have a <mother-composant></mother-composant>

Comment: @r-sede updated answer. basically, you just pass the element name as the parameter, much like you would with `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` works fine for me

you can use `document.querySelectorAll` if you want to look for specific attributes for example `document.querySelectorAll('img[title]')` (all images with a title attribute)

```js
console.log( Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('randomComponent')) );
```

```css
randomComponent {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #6F6;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<randomComponent id="1"></randomComponent>
<randomComponent id="2"></randomComponent>
```

Comment: yes this is the solution i'm using now, all my childCpomposant have a same attribute and i use ""const translatableNode = document.querySelectorAll('[i18n]')"

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that all the custom elements you select by attributes with `querySelector()` are really inheriting from a specific Javascript class, you should test each element whith [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```
window.onload = function() {
    const els = document.querySelectorAll( '[i18n]' ) 
    const translatableNodes = Array.from(els).filter( el => el instanceof LspTranslatable )
}
```